# Quora API - logging in?

Tags: api, make.com, quora

Quora has an unsupported, limited, undocumented API.
You can get your notifications via this URL: https://www.quora.com/api/logged_in_user?fields=inbox,notifs

As the API is expecting a logged_in_user, is there a way to make an HTTP Auth request to get the JSON output of the notifications?

I want to use integromat (make.com) and fetch my notifications automatically

Tried using credentials with an OAuth HTTP module, without success